# Vertical align pull-right not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a table in which some of the `<td>`'s are filled with some text after which I put an icon in using [Font Awesome icons](http://fontawesome.io/). The text is vertical aligned in the middle, but the icon isn't and I can't seem to figure out how to align it. I suspect it's because of the added 'pull-right' class to the `i class`, but definitely not sure about that.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LjETb/1/

Comment: The icon is `display:inline-block`, yeah?

Comment: @MikeBarwick Yes, that doesn't do anything.

Comment: K. It'd be nice if we had some code to work with...like a jsFiddle or URL.

Comment: @MikeBarwick I've added a jsfiddle :)

Comment: looks fine in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone still looking at this, the problem is the .pull-right class, which adds a float:right to the element and screws up the line-height.

To fix, change the line-height of the target element to match its parent. To do this globally:

```
.fa.pull-right,
.fa.fa-pull-right,
[class*=" fa-"].pull-right,
[class*=" fa-"].fa-pull-right {
  line-height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **common fix**. I experience this issue a lot with icon fonts quite a bit. I'm nit-picky just as you are (it appears). Icon fonts tend to offset about -2px from the top. I typically just add a couple pixels to the top of most of my icons sets. Unless someone else has a better solution (Bootstrap doesn't...only because it can vary based on use)...but this is a common issue to people with a *keen eye*. ;)

Do this to apply it to all your icons:

```
[class*=" fa-"]{
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LjETb/4/